# old yAxis ticks do not get removed (chartjs, react-chartjs-2 wrapper)

Tags: javascript, chart.js, react-chartjs-2

When i draw a chart with 4 lines, each with its own data ofc, i programmatically create the options for the LineChart that has 4 Yaxis, first one on the left and the rest on the right side. Now, after the chart is drawn and i de-select some datasources from the list (less lines to draw), the now-obsolete yAxis ticks stay there, even when the chart correctly draws only the selected lines, and the options are updated as well correctly. I cant think of a way to remove them!

I have googled for 2 days and cant find a solution. I am using react in functional style and it makes things more complicated because every advice seems to be in the classic style.
I am using react-chartjs-2 wrapper as well, if this helps.
I am also quite new to react, and asking in Stackoverflow, so please cut me some slack :)
I assume the chart is being re-rendered or something because the amount of lines etc do change.

In the images, the "createYaxis" that is shown in the console.log is the generated yAxes- part of the options object (which is functional otherwise). The problem yAxises are on the right side in red and yellow. Images show before and after situation.

[image]

[image]

Image of the options-object generated by the code below the img:
[image]

```
    var yAxisItems = [];
  function createYaxises (num){
    var arr = [];
for (var i=0;i<num.length;i++){
  
  if (i===0){
    arr.push({
 
          display: true,
          id: i,
          type: 'linear',
          position: 'left',
          gridLines: {
            display:false,
            
            //color: 'blue'
        },
        ticks: {
         fontColor: lineColourArray[i],
         fontSize: 14,
     }
           })
          }
        else {
          arr.push({
 
            display: true,
            id: i,
            type: 'linear',
            position: 'right',
            gridLines: {
              display:false,
              
              //color: 'blue'
          },
          ticks: {
            display:true,
           fontColor: lineColourArray[i],
           fontSize: 14,
       }
      })
        }}
        yAxisItems = arr;
        console.log("createyaxis arr: " , arr);
        console.log("createyaxis: " , yAxisItems); //JSON.stringify(yAxisItems));
}

 //get data for selected sensors and set it to chart data 
  const handleGetSelectedSensorData = function () {
    
    var d = getSelectedSensorData();
 console.log("d: ", d);
    var dSets = [];
    if (d[0]){
      d.map((dItem,index)=> {
       var newDsetData =[];
       if (dItem.data){
          dItem.data.map((innerDataItem)=> {
            var dSet = {};
            dSet.x =  innerDataItem.timestamp;
            dSet.y = innerDataItem.v;
            newDsetData.push(dSet);
          })
        
        var newset = {
          data: newDsetData,
          label: dItem.sensorTag,
          borderColor: lineColourArray[index],
          fill: false,
          pointRadius: 1.5,
          backgroundColor:lineColourArray[index],
          borderWidth: 2,
          showLine: true,
          pointHoverRadius: 5,
          lineTension: 1,
 
        };
         
          dSets.push(newset);
      }}) 
 
      var dDataTemp = {};
      var optionsTemp = new Object();
 
    dDataTemp.datasets =dSets;
    //create yaxises only once
   
 
    createYaxises(dDataTemp.datasets);
       //more than one set (TODO)
       //console.log("dDataTemp.datasets : ", dDataTemp.datasets)
        if (dDataTemp.datasets.length >1){
          console.log("dset > 1");
         
         for(var i=0;i< dDataTemp.datasets.length;i++) {
          dDataTemp.datasets[i].yAxisID = i;
            console.log("setting options");
      
            optionsTemp ={
              tooltips: {
                enabled: true, 
                intersect:false,
                mode:'x',
                  
              callbacks: {
                title: function(tooltipItem, data) {
                  var toSplit = tooltipItem[0].label.split(",");
                  return (toSplit[0]);
                },
                label: function (tooltipItem) {
                  var split = tooltipItem.xLabel.split(',');
                    //return ( Number(tooltipItem.yLabel).toFixed(3));
                    return (split[2] + " : " + Number(tooltipItem.yLabel).toFixed(3)); 
                }
              },
              },
              hover: {
                mode: 'nearest',
                intersect: true,
              },
     
                title:{
                  display:true,
                  text:'Valittu sensoridata',
                  fontSize:20
                      },
                  legend:{
                    display:true,
                    position:'right'
                  },
                  scales: {
                     xAxes: [{
                      display: true,
                      type: 'time',

                      ticks: {
                      }
                    }],
                       yAxes: 
                        yAxisItems
                    }
        }
          }
      setOptions(optionsTemp);
      console.log("options: " , optionsTemp);
      setdData(dDataTemp);
}}


    else {
      console.log("error in handleGetSelectedSensorData()");
    }
  }
```

And the Line is just added like this:

```
<Line data={dData} options = {options} />
```

Comment: addition: when i mean i remove 2 lines, i mean that i re-fetch the data, and re-draw the map, not select from legend to hide the 2 lines.

Comment: Please provide the options and code you use to generate the chart etc, because its guess work to why its going wrong now

Comment: nobody has found any clues? :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of setting `display: true` set `display: 'auto'`, this will make the axis dissapear as long as there is no dataset visable that is linked to that scale, as soon as a dataset becomes visable that is linked to that scale it will show the scale again.

Doc: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/master/axes/cartesian/#common-options-to-all-axes